# In the ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK, does the order of Language parameter values matter?

Tags: ocr, abbyy

When using the the ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK, one of the optional parameters is "language," which will accept a comma-separated list of languages the service should look for when recognizing the text.  Does anyone know if the order of these matters?  For example, when calling the `processBusinessCard` method as documented [here](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processBusinessCard/)

Would a language option of `English,Japanese` behave any differently from `Japanese,English` - for example by preferring the detection of one language over the other?

I'm trying to decide if I can use a simple checkbox group to set the values for this setting, or if I need to provide an interface that allows for ordering.

UPDATE:
I've tested reordering the languages, and it doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know there is no difference. But to be sure you can upload sample image into [demo-service](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Demo?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) and to try both ways.

A little tip: you can use [ABBYY OCR SDK forum](http://forum.ocrsdk.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) for contacting support team.